# my cat loves my bed - why?

Tags: cats

Is it the springiness of the mattress?

I am getting a new bed (for me) and thought that I could use my old bed for my cat. But this means paying somebody to saw the mattress into a size that fits my bedroom. Will this be worth it? Will my cat like it?

I hate to wake her up from my bed, but she leaves once I sit on the bed, she knows I will soon be in it, and take up too much space for her liking, and so she leaves. But she does love the bed lately, in spite of her several other cosy sleeping spots.

Comment: My cat also loves my bed and it easily fits two of us.  I think she loves to be with me. Because she uses the bed only when I am on it. When I am on a sofa she sits on the next sofa. When I am in balcony she is also in balcony and so on, she loves me.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do an experiment and have the two mattresses in your room for just a day or two, that would make you figure out if it's worth it or not. Also you'd probably see that your cat would like spending time on your new mattress as well. It may even prefer the new one and never use the old one. It may like your bed because it smells like you or just like it because its comfortable. So thats another reason for you to do the experiment. At the end if you ask my opinion I'd say yes it's worth it but after the experiment.